# finding conditional expectation under binomial distribution.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose X and Y independent and are both binomial random variables with parameter N, p Compute E(X|X+Y).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By symmetry, this is $E(Y|X+Y)$. Given that $X+Y=w$, what is $E(X+Y)$?